# programmatically remove all html and inline formatting

Tags: asp.net, css

I have taken over a code base and I have to read in these html files that were generated by Microsoft Word, I think so it has all kinds of whacky inline formatting.

is there anyway to parse out all of the bad inline formatting and just get the text from this stream. I basically want a purifier programmatically so I can then apply some sensible css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end i just wrote a small class that did a bunch of find and replaces.  not pretty but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) - it's uniquitous when it comes to cleansing HTML. There's an [article on DevX that describes how to do it from .NET](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/20505).